# Safety of user-supplied LESS

Tags: css, less

As part of my forum system, there is a means for users to include LESS in their posts. The post content is wrapped in a `uniqid`-referenced ID and the LESS is wrapped in `#IDhere {... }`. This gives users full flexibility in their posts.

To my knowledge there is no way to break out of the block, and to ensure this the LESS is syntax-checked *without* the wrapping before compiling it with the wrapper. This prevents the trick of just closing the wrapper and defining styles that would end up not bring wrapped (and simply leaving the final `}` to be added by the wrapper)

I can't think of any problems here, but I'd like another set of eyes on this! Have I missed anything that would let a user style things not inside their designated container?

Answer (score 1):

> Have I missed anything that would let a user style things not inside their designated container?

Yes. Any usage of `&` would allow the user to place the selector for the wrapping element wherever they'd like, which allows usage along the lines of:

```
p:not(&) {
    ...
}
```

Which when nested in something like:

```
#uniqid {
    p:not(&) {
        ...
    }
}
```

produces:

```
p:not(#uniqid) {
    ...
}
```

Which would affect *every* `p` element assuming that you enforce unique IDs.

Comment: Ooh, good catch. Okay, is there a general rule here that I can restrict to patch this issue? I kind of don't want to restrict `&` entirely if I can help it, but if there's no easy rule to prevent the issue then I guess that would patch it...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, using `&` was just the first way I thought of that would break selector namespacing. I believe there may be other ways to hijack selectors, but I haven't spent a lot of time going down that rabbit hole. I think it's possible to use string interpolation to generate selectors, which would allow users to just prefix their desired global selector with `,` so as to escape the namespacing ID.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, I just confirmed that selector interpolation can be used to escape a namespacing ID http://codepen.io/zzzzBov/pen/ojMxmM/. Also be aware that CSS has been used as an attack vector (e.x. http://mksben.l0.cm/2015/10/css-based-attack-abusing-unicode-range.html) and that for older browsers CSS was once able to trigger JavaScript, so consider restricting what users can do, and be sure to thoroughly sandbox anything they can control.

Comment: All right, thank you for your info. Looks like this feature needs a lot more work.